# OpenJFX 9-dev XYChart.java...is this a bug?

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception

I have been browsing through the source code relating to JavaFX charts lately, and I came across the following method:

```
/**
 * This should be called from seriesRemoved() when you are finished with any animation for deleting the series from
 * the chart. It will remove the series from showing up in the Iterator returned by getDisplayedSeriesIterator().
 *
 * @param series The series to remove
 */
protected final void removeSeriesFromDisplay(Series<X, Y> series) {
    if (series != null) series.setToRemove = false;
    series.setChart(null);
    displayedSeries.remove(series);
}
```

Here: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/9-dev/rt/file/9c2e8ff4fa26/modules/controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.java#l910

If the series passed in is null, there is nothing to keep from making the call `series.setChart(null);` which will, if series is null, cause a `NullPointerException`. Given that the method is protected and therefore visible to sub-classes, shouldn't the if statement contain brackets that surround the entire method? Essentially:

```
/**
 * This should be called from seriesRemoved() when you are finished with any animation for deleting the series from
 * the chart. It will remove the series from showing up in the Iterator returned by getDisplayedSeriesIterator().
 *
 * @param series The series to remove
 */
protected final void removeSeriesFromDisplay(Series<X, Y> series) {
    if (series != null) {
        series.setToRemove = false;
        series.setChart(null);
    }
    displayedSeries.remove(series);
}
```

Given that the OpenJFX authors are much better programmers than I am, I am hesitant to report this as a bug, especially given that I am not setup to do so (via their JIRA system or their mailing lists, I wanted to ask more knowledgeable folks than me before I proceed to embarrass myself!)

Comment: Either series can't be null and the null check is unnecessary or it can be null and the method can throw NPE on the 2nd statement. That is an inconsistency which should probably be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the verification, it made me feel confident enough to posted the issue on the OpenJFX Jira: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-40402

Comment: Updated issue link: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8089708